# How can I remove all characters before the pipe (||) symbol?

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove everything before the pipe but my code below does not work.  I have string like this

```
0145 || myTest
```

I am only interested to get the string myTest so i want to remove everything before myTest including the white space.  Here is my code:

```
string MyFilter;
        MyFilter = ddl_ProjectName.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string result = MyFilter.Substring("||");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the pipe:

```
string MyFilter = "0145 || myTest";
string result = MyFilter.Substring(MyFilter.IndexOf("||"))
```

If you want to remove the pipe:

```
string MyFilter = "0145 || myTest";
string result = MyFilter.Substring(MyFilter.IndexOf("||") + 2)
```

If you want to remove the pipe and any spaces at the beginning:

```
string MyFilter = "0145 || myTest";
string result = MyFilter.Substring(MyFilter.IndexOf("||") + 2).TrimStart();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 :**

```
String str = "0145 || myTest";
string searchKey="||";
string result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(searchKey) + searchKey.Length).Trim();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
 String str = "0145 || myTest";  
 String result = str.Split(new []{"||"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim();
```